# How to identify relationship type (Lookup / Master detail) from the field api Name in APEX?

Tags: apex, relationships

I have requirement in which i iterate through all fields of sObject and needs to identify fields which has master detail relation ship only and then get that (Reference to)object name and then further logic.

**so, I need help to get Name of this Master Object.**

what i am trying to do it now is,

```
//here, key is comming from iteration over a map which is String.
Schema.SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(Key);  // sObject token 
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMapForChild = objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String fieldNameChild : fieldMapForChild.keySet()) { 
    Schema.SObjectField fieldChild = fieldMapForChild.get(fieldNameChild);      //field token
    Schema.DisplayType FldTypeChild = fieldChild.getDescribe().getType();       //type of field.
    String fieldTypeChild = String.valueOf(FldTypeChild);                       //string value of type.

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr1 = fieldMapForChild.get(fieldNameChild).getDescribe();   

    //Here , I want fields which has Master detail relation ship and name of that Master Object.
    if(fieldTypeChild == 'REFERENCE' ){  // this will true for lookup and master detail both.
        String RelatedObjNameChild = String.valueOf(dfr1.getReferenceTo()).substringBetween('(',')');  // Related Object name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the [getRelationshipOrder()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getRelationshipOrder) method available in the [DescribeFieldResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) class. This is populated only for Master-Detail relationships and is null for lookup relationships.

> [RelationShipOrder](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#i1427375) : The type of relationship for a master-detail relationship field. Valid
>   values are:
>
> - 0 if the field is the primary relationship
> - 1 if the field is the    secondary relationship

Also, to get the name of the Master Object, you need to use the [getReferenceTo()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getReferenceTo) method.

> **[getReferenceTo()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getReferenceTo)** : Returns a list of Schema.sObjectType objects for the
>   parent objects of this field. If the isNamePointing method returns
>   true, there is more than one entry in the list, otherwise there is
>   only one.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I don't see `getRelationshipOrder()` giving out null for lookups. The docs says that "getRelationshipOrder()
Returns 1 if the field is a child, 0 otherwise" does not mean that 0 is a parent. This just determines that if the value is 1, then the field is a detail in master detail and `getReferenceTo()` retrieves the master object name. Not all fields that have 0 mean that it is a lookup (may not participate in a relationship at all). How can I determine that if a field is involved in lookup relationship? What is the difference between this method and using `DescribeSObjectResult`?

Comment: `getRelationshipOrder()` indeed returns null for Lookups and returns not null for Master-Detail.   Try it out in an Apex Test

Comment: hm seeing null for WorkOrderLineItem lookup to Work Order

Comment: @PhilB, that's strange.  I see it too.  And `WorkOrderLineItem.WorkOrderId` **is** a Master-Detail relationship to `WorkOrder`.