# Is account have master details or lookup to opporunity

Tags: opportunity, account, master-detail

We have `Opportunity` records without a related `Account`. As far as I remember, `Account` and `Opportunity` have a `Master Detail` relationship. Is there some thing I am missing?

Comment: It is combination of both as, You can able to create a Roll Up Summary Fields (Master-Detail) and You can able to create a Opportunity without providing a Account reference (Lookup). Sometimes, it is referred as  a Special Kind of Relationship. I am trying to get a Salesforce documentation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is simply a lookup.

[image: AccountId Field]

You can also look at its describe information as laid out here: [How to identify relationship type (Lookup / Master detail) from the field api Name in APEX?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73405/how-to-identify-relationship-type-lookup-master-detail-from-the-field-api-na)

```
system.debug(Opportunity.AccountId.getDescribe().getRelationshipOrder()); // yields null
```

Since the relationship order of this field is `null`, that further confirms the relationship is simply a `Lookup`. It gets some special treatment based on delivered Ideas, for example: [Roll-up Summary Fields for Account - Opportunity Standard Relationship](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BraSAAS).

Comment: Great findings Adrian, Much appreciated :)